# Zoom in RecyclerView Android

Tags: android

i am facing one issue, i want to Implement pinch zoom in RecyclerView.

Here is the Layout of my recyclerview

[image]

actually, i'm done with the zoom using this code, but i cannot click on recyclerview items after use the zoom code

```
public class ZoomRelative extends RelativeLayout implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

    //ScalingFactor i.e. Amount of Zoom
    static float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;

    // Maximum and Minimum Zoom
    private static float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
    private static float MAX_ZOOM = 3.0f;

    private enum Mode {
        NONE,
        DRAG,
        ZOOM
    }

    private Mode mode1 = Mode.NONE;

    //Different Operation to be used
    private final int NONE_OPERATION=0;
    private final int ZOOM_OPERATION=2;
    private float mWidth= 1280;
    private float mHeight=800;

    // Mode to select the operation
    private int mode;

    //Track X and Y coordinate of the finger when it first touches the screen
    private float mInitialX = 0f;
    private float mInitialY = 0f;

    private float dx = 0f;
    private float dy = 0f;

    private float prevX = 0f;
    private float preyY = 0f;

    // Track the Bound of the Image after zoom to calculate the offset
    static Rect mClipBound;

    // mDetector to detect the scaleGesture for the pinch Zoom
    private ScaleGestureDetector mDetector;

    //Pivot point for Scaling
    static float gx=0,gy=0;


    /*
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    *
    *  @description : Constructor is called when used via XML
    *
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    */

    public ZoomRelative(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        mClipBound = new Rect();
        // Intialize ScaleGestureDetector
        mDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ZoomListener());
    }



    /*
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    *
    *  @description : Constructor is called when used via code
    *
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    */
    public ZoomRelative(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        mClipBound = new Rect();
        // Intialize ScaleGestureDetector
        mDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ZoomListener());
    }

    /*
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    *
    *  @description : OnTouchEvent of the layout which handles all type of motion-events possible
    *  @ Returns : true  - we are handling the touchEvent.
    *
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // Handles all type of motion-events possible
        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                if (mScaleFactor > MIN_ZOOM) {
                    mode1 = Mode.NONE;
                    mInitialX = event.getX() - prevX;
                    mInitialY = event.getY() - preyY;
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode1 == Mode.DRAG) {
                    mInitialX = event.getX() - prevX;
                    mInitialY = event.getY() - preyY;
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                //Event occurs when the second finger is pressed down

                Log.d("Print", "Event: Action_Pointer_Down " );
                // If second finger is pressed on the screen with the first set the Mode to Zoom operation

                mode1 = Mode.ZOOM;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //Event occurs when all the finger are taken of the screen
                Log.d("Print", "Event: Action_UP " );
                //If all the fingers are taken up there will be no operation
                mode1 = Mode.NONE;

                if (mScaleFactor > 1)
                {
                    gx = gx - (event.getX() - mInitialX);
                    gy = gy - (event.getY() - mInitialY);
                    invalidate();
                    requestLayout();
                }


                break;
        }

        // Give the event to the mDetector to get the scaling Factor
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        if ((mode1 == Mode.DRAG && mScaleFactor >= MIN_ZOOM) || mode1 == Mode.ZOOM) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            float maxDx = (child().getWidth() - (child().getWidth() / mScaleFactor)) / 2 * mScaleFactor;
            float maxDy = (child().getHeight() - (child().getHeight() / mScaleFactor))/ 2 * mScaleFactor;
            prevX = Math.min(Math.max(prevX, -maxDx), maxDx);
            preyY = Math.min(Math.max(preyY, -maxDy), maxDy);

            applyScaleAndTranslation();
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void applyScaleAndTranslation() {
        child().setScaleX(mScaleFactor);
        child().setScaleY(mScaleFactor);
        child().setTranslationX(prevX);
        child().setTranslationY(preyY);
    }

    private View child() {
        return getChildAt(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        onTouchEvent(ev);
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);

    }

    @Override
    public ViewParent invalidateChildInParent(int[] location, Rect dirty) {
        return super.invalidateChildInParent(location, dirty);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        int count = getChildCount();
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if(child.getVisibility()!=GONE){
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();
                child.layout(
                        (int)(params.leftMargin ),
                        (int)(params.topMargin ),
                        (int)((params.leftMargin + child.getMeasuredWidth()) ),
                        (int)((params.topMargin + child.getMeasuredHeight()))
                );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        //Save the canvas to set the scaling factor returned from detector
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);

        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,gx,gy);

        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        mClipBound = canvas.getClipBounds();

        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ZoomListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // getting the scaleFactor from the detector
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor(); // Gives the scaling factor from the previous scaling to the current
            //    Log.d("Print", "detector scaling Factor" + mScaleFactor);

            gx = detector.getFocusX();
            gy = detector.getFocusY();
            // Limit the scale factor in the MIN and MAX bound
            mScaleFactor= Math.max(Math.min(mScaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM),MIN_ZOOM);
            //    Log.d("Print", "Bounded scaling Factor" + mScaleFactor);

            /*//Force canvas to redraw itself only if the one event is to happen (say Zooming only ) else do not invalidate here for multi operations
               As what we de for scrolling or panning will not reflect here. So we will add this in onDraw method
            invalidate();*/
            // Here we are only zooming so invalidate has to be done
            invalidate();
            requestLayout();

            // we have handle the onScale
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                           float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and call it on xml like this

```
<com.itams.visionet.customerserviceapps.animation.ZoomRelative
    android:layout_below="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5sp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</com.itams.visionet.customerserviceapps.animation.ZoomRelative>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used a custom class to perform pinch zoom in and out on recyclerview.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class PinchZoomRecyclerView : RecyclerView {
    private var mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID
    private var mScaleDetector: ScaleGestureDetector? = null
    private var mScaleFactor = 1f
    private var maxWidth = 0.0f
    private var maxHeight = 0.0f
    private var mLastTouchX: Float = 0.toFloat()
    private var mLastTouchY: Float = 0.toFloat()
    private var mPosX: Float = 0.toFloat()
    private var mPosY: Float = 0.toFloat()
    private var width: Float = 0.toFloat()
    private var height: Float = 0.toFloat()
    private var minZoom = 1.0f
    private var maxZoom = 3.0f


    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        if (!isInEditMode)
            mScaleDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), ScaleListener())
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        if (!isInEditMode)
            mScaleDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), ScaleListener())
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        if (!isInEditMode)
            mScaleDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), ScaleListener())
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec).toFloat()
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec).toFloat()
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        try {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
        } catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }

        return false
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev)
        val action = ev.action
        mScaleDetector!!.onTouchEvent(ev)
        when (action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                val x = ev.x
                val y = ev.y
                mLastTouchX = x
                mLastTouchY = y
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0)
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                val pointerIndex =
                    action and MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK shr MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT
                val x = ev.getX(pointerIndex)
                val y = ev.getY(pointerIndex)
                val dx = x - mLastTouchX
                val dy = y - mLastTouchY

                mPosX += dx
                mPosY += dy

                if (mPosX > 0.0f) mPosX = 0.0f
                else if (mPosX < maxWidth) mPosX = maxWidth

                if (mPosY > 0.0f) mPosY = 0.0f
                else if (mPosY < maxHeight) mPosY = maxHeight

                mLastTouchX = x
                mLastTouchY = y

                invalidate()
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP -> {
                val pointerIndex =
                    action and MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK shr MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT
                val pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex)
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    val newPointerIndex = if (pointerIndex == 0) 1 else 0
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex)
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex)
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex)
                }
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.save()
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY)
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor)
        canvas.restore()
    }

    override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.save()
        if (mScaleFactor == minZoom) {
            mPosX = 0.0f
            mPosY = 0.0f
        }
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY)
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor)
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas)
        canvas.restore()
        invalidate()
    }

    private inner class ScaleListener : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
        override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.scaleFactor
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(minZoom, Math.min(mScaleFactor, maxZoom))

            if (mScaleFactor < 3f) {
                val centerX = detector.focusX
                val centerY = detector.focusY
                var diffX = centerX - mPosX
                var diffY = centerY - mPosY
                diffX = diffX * detector.scaleFactor - diffX
                diffY = diffY * detector.scaleFactor - diffY
                mPosX -= diffX
                mPosY -= diffY
            }

            maxWidth = width - width * mScaleFactor
            maxHeight = height - height * mScaleFactor

            invalidate()
            return true
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1
    }
}
```

and after this just use PinchZoomRecyclerView as a replacement of recyclerview in your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

In this function, you have to return true =)

`@Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }`

Any progress on this functionality?

I tried what you have but the zoom is very unstable when dragging the component